# How to switch off the URL field in bibliographic items?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, harvard-style

I am using a paper template which has the following code:

```
\usepackage{natbib,har2nat} % for references in harvard+dcu style
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}{\footnotesize{\textbf{URL:} \url}}"
```

I want to turn off printing of the URL in the bibliography. I searched the package manual book but couldn't find the way. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Mico Thanks!!!

Comment: You're most welcome! Just out of curiosity: which bibliography style do you employ? If you believe that my answer has fully addressed your typesetting concern, feel free to "accept" it by clicking on the "checkmark" symbol. ;-)

Comment: @Mico you are correct on the style I'm using :). Answer has been accepted! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you're using one of the bibliography styles provided by the [harvard package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/), e.g., `dcu` or `agsm`. If this assumption is correct, and if the line-spacing in your document is not "too unorthodox" -- aside: if you use the `setspace` package, you should be ok -- you may suppress the printing of the contents of the `url` fields by issuing the instruction

```
\renewcommand\harvardurl[1]{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
```

toward the end of the preamble. (You should, of course, also delete the template-provided `\renewcommand{\harvardurl}{\footnotesize{\textbf{URL:} \url}}` instruction.)

This works because the `harvard`-package bibliography styles provide a BibTeX function called `write.url`, which is defined as follows:

```
FUNCTION {write.url}
{ URL empty$
    { skip$ }
    { "\newline\harvardurl{" URL * "}" * write$ newline$ }
  if$
}
```

Even if you're not familiar with the syntax of BibTeX's programming language, it is hopefully clear that the function begins its work by testing if the `url` field is empty. If that's *not* the case, a `\newline` directive is executed, followed by a `\harvardurl` instruction (whose argument is a URL string). It's therefore not enough to redefine `\harvardurl` to simply "do nothing with the URL string" via `\renewcommand\harvardurl[1]{}`, as that would fail to remove the effect of the preceding `\newline` directive. Hence my suggested solution, which (a) deliberately discards the macro's argument (the URL string) and (b) executes `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` to undo the effect of the preceding `\newline` instruction.

Of course, one could also modify a (copy of the) bibliography style file and redefine `write.url` so that it does nothing at all in case the `url` field is non-empty. However, that may be well be overkill for the case at hand.